# Change Toggle Switch status dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring

I am trying to figure out how to set toggle switch button base on a value. I am using bootstrap for the button. Anyone please tell me what is wrong?

*user.isActive only have two value either true or false.

```
<td><input id="activeSwitch" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Active" data-off="InActive" data-onstyle="danger" data-width="90" data-height="30" style="font-size:38px" type="checkbox">
<input type="hidden" id="activeStatus" value='${user.isActive}'/></td>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {

                if($('#activeStatus').val() == 'true'){
                      $("#activeSwitch").attr("checked", "checked");
                }

                else if($('#activeStatus').val() == 'false'){
                     ...
                }
            });  
</script>
```

Comment: Use `prop`. $('#activeSwitch').prop('checked', $('#activeStatus').val() === 'true')`.

Comment: @Tushar nope,it's not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer so wanted to share with people who need help too. For people using bootstrap use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

              if ($('#activeStatus').val().trim() == 'true') {
                  $("#activeSwitch").bootstrapToggle('on');
              } else if ($('#activeStatus').val().trim() == 'false') {
                  $("#activeSwitch").bootstrapToggle('off');
              }
            });
```

Use `.bootstrap('on')` instead of prop or attr if they are not working.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this [`prop()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjb4KmXgPTUAhVErY8KHbkzC6AQFggoMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fprop%2F&usg=AFQjCNHaMBB-3221pUloi4_sHJpwg7mWnA) instead of `attr` => `prop('checked',true)`. use Boolean value instead of string

**updated**

Do with `trim()` its remove the unwanted space

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  if ($('#activeStatus').val().trim() == 'true') {
    $("#activeSwitch").prop("checked", true);
  } else if ($('#activeStatus').val().trim() == 'false') {
        $("#activeSwitch").prop("checked", false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td><input id="activeSwitch" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Active" data-off="InActive" data-onstyle="danger" data-width="90" data-height="30" style="font-size:38px" type="checkbox">
  <input type="hidden" id="activeStatus" value='true' /></td>
```

**or single line code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#activeSwitch").prop("checked" , $('#activeStatus').val().trim() == 'true')
 })
```

Comment: ok lets check the id of  `activeStatus` and `activeSwitch` is else where in the document.its unique one?

Comment: kindly `console.log($('#activeStatus').val())`.They input value is correct or not .And showing your console.log error `F12`

Comment: i tried the if else condition and it seems to be working perfectly fine just that i am unable to set the toggle switch to data-off or data-on

Comment: I have found the answer to my qns! Is  $("#activeSwitch").bootstrapToggle('on'); instead. Thank you for your time anyways!